# Saving numpy arrays as a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I'm saving 2 Numpy arrays as a dictionary.
When I load the data from the binary file, I get another `ndarray`. Can I use the loaded Numpy array as a dictionary?


Here is my code and the output of my script:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107])
z = {'X': x, 'Y': y}
np.save('./data.npy', z)
z1 = np.load('./data.npy')
print(type(z1))
print(z1)
print(z1['X']) #this line will generate an error
```

> Output: {'X': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 'Y': array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107])}

Comment: I use `pickle` for saving dictionaries. It's really easy to use

Comment: ... what error?

Comment: did you notice you used capital Z instead of z when the error is generated?

Comment: `np.save` saves arrays.  If given some other structure it first wraps it in an object dtype array.  `pickle` can save a dictionary direct, and will use `save` internally to write the arrays. In fact, `save` uses `pickle` to handle the dictionary part of the save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can access the underlying dictionary in a 0-dimensional array. Try `z1[()]`.

Here's a demo:

```
np.save('./data.npy', z)
d = np.load('./data.npy')[()]

print(type(d))
<class 'dict'>

print(d['X'])
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to access data from `z1` should be:

```
z1.flatten()[0]['X']
```

Comment: In other words, turn the 0d array into a 1d one, and use `[(0,)]` indexing instead of `[()]`,  The argument of an indexing expression is always a tuple, whether the `()` are explicit or not.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and underused method of storing `numpy` arrays is HDF5. The benefits are:

- Transportability, i.e. not Python-specific like `pickle`
- Ability to access data out-of-memory & chunking options for optimisation
- Compression options to optimize read or write performance

Here's a demo:

```
import h5py, numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107])
z = {'X': x, 'Y': y}

with h5py.File('file.h5', 'w', libver='latest') as f:  # use 'latest' for performance
    for k, v in z.items():
        f.create_dataset('dict/'+str(k), data=v)

with h5py.File('file.h5', 'r', libver='latest') as f:
    x_read = f['dict']['X'][:]  # [:] syntax extracts numpy array into memory
    y_read = f['dict']['Y'][:]

print(x_read)

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```